# Javascript files only merge once, sass files not working

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using a task in `Gulp` to select all `.js` files in a folder and merge them to one file in another folder. When I type `gulp` in `terminal` it connects to the server and merge the `.js` files, however when I save in one of the `.js` files it doesn't update...

Also, even though I have a task that has to reload the browser on change, it doesn't.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var jquery = require('jquery');
var minify = require('gulp-minify-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('connect',function(){
    connect.server({
       root: 'public',
        port: 4000
    });
});

//Save sass file to style.css
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return sass('css/style.scss')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('javascript', function() {
    gulp.src('assets/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify()).on('error', errorHandler)
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'watch']);


gulp.task('serve', ['sass', 'javascript'], function () {
    browserSync({
        proxy: 'http://localhost:4000'
    });
    gulp.watch('assets/sass/*.scss', ['sass', browserSync.reload]);
    gulp.watch('assets/js/**/*.js', ['javascript', browserSync.reload]);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve', 'connect']);

function errorHandler (error) {
    console.log(error.toString());
    this.emit('end');
}
```

Comment: are you sure your js files do not have any syntax errors?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. It has for the moment only an `alert message` on `document.ready`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the way you are using `browserSync.reload`. Try this:

1) Create the browserSync instance. Put this at the top `var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();` by replacing your `var browserSync = require('browser-sync'); var reload = browserSync.reload;`.

2) Remove wherever you are doing `.pipe(reload({stream: true}));`.

3) Next, modify your "serve" task. It's nice to have only one line executing the reload. The last `gulp.watch()` below checks your build `public` directory for changes, and if there any, it reloads. No need to have a separate reload for both your "sass" and "javascript" tasks. Also, notice that we are calling `browserSync.init()`.

```
gulp.task('serve', ['sass', 'javascript'], function () {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'http://localhost:4000'
    });
    gulp.watch('assets/sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('assets/js/**/*.js', ['javascript']);
    gulp.watch('public/**/*.{css,js}').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: @Greg - no problem! glad that you got it working. :)